# recursive reduce arrays using jq

Tags: jq

How can I recursive find all arrays in object and reduce them to first item ?

I tried to detect array using `if .[0]? == "" then .[0] else . end` but it not output anything if current object is not array.

input:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  "c": [
    {
      "a": 1,
      "b": [
        1,
        2,
        3
      ],
      "c": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": [
          1,
          2,
          3
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "a": 1,
      "b": [
        1,
        2,
        3
      ],
      "c": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": [
          1,
          2,
          3
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "a": 1,
      "b": [
        1,
        2,
        3
      ],
      "c": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": [
          1,
          2,
          3
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

output:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": [
    1
  ],
  "c": [
    {
      "a": 1,
      "b": [
        1
      ],
      "c": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": [
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

peak's answer is great. This problem can also be solved using recursion, but it is not obvious how to make it work.

The naïve solution I came up with was `(.. | arrays) |= .[0]`, but that doesn't work because the recursion is done from the outside, which means that on nested cases we end up trying to get .[0] from values who are no longer arrays.

This can be solved by doing post-order traversal, as explained [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/893).

With `post_recurse`, it's just a matter of replacing `..` with `post_recurse` in the naïve solution above. The full solution:

```
def post_recurse(f): def r: (f | select(. != null) | r), .; r; def post_recurse: post_recurse(.[]?); (post_recurse | arrays) |= .[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

walk/1 is included in recent (post-1.5) releases of jq.  Its definition is also available below.

Here's how it can be used to achieve your objective as I understand it:

```
walk(if type == "array" and length > 1 then [.[0]] else . end)
```

---

```
# Apply f to composite entities recursively, and to atoms
def walk(f):
  . as $in
  | if type == "object" then
      reduce keys_unsorted[] as $key
        ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | walk(f)) } ) | f
  elif type == "array" then map( walk(f) ) | f
  else f
  end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using **tostream** which converts the input object
into a stream of paths, filters out any paths with nonzero array indices
and converts the result back to an object using **reduce** and **setpath**.   All the recursion is internal to **tostream**.

```
[
  tostream

| if   length != 2 then empty
  elif ([.[0][]|numbers|.!=0]|any) then empty
  else .
  end
]

| reduce .[] as $p (
    {};     
    setpath($p[0]; $p[1])
  )
```