# JQ delete multiple properties

Tags: json, jq

I have an object like this:

```
{
    "a" : 1,
    "b" : {
        "c" : {
            "c1" : "abc",
            "source" : "abcxyz"
        },
        "d" : {
            "d1" : "abcd",
            "source" : "abcxyz"
        },
        "e" : {
            "e1" : "abcde",
            "source" : "abcxyz"
        }
    }
}
```

My expectation is

```
{
    "a" : 1,
    "b" : {
        "c" : {
            "c1" : "abc"
        },
        "d" : {
            "d1" : "abcd"
        },
        "e" : {
            "e1" : "abcde"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to remove "source" properties. How can I do that without specifying keys "c", "d" or "e", because they are dynamic.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Iterate through all the elements in `.b`, then set their value to the result of removing the `.source` element from them:

```
.b[] |= del(.source)
```

Comment: https://jqplay.org/s/sMDcaUhWwt

Answer (score 19):

Here is another solution

```
del( .b[].source )
```

Comment: this - worked for me better, my removed attribute is an array, which gave a wierd error like `error: my-attribute/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1`

Answer (score 4):

May be in next release of jq you can use builtin function `walk/1`.
But current jq-1.5 don't have `walk/1` so you have to copy it from `buitin.jq`
https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq

save following code as `hoo.jq`

```
def walk(f):
  . as $in
  | if type == "object" then
      reduce keys[] as $key
        ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | walk(f)) } ) | f
    elif type == "array" then map( walk(f) ) | f
    else f
    end;

walk(if type == "object" then del(.source) else . end)
```

run

```
$ jq -f hoo.jq < YOUR_JSON.json
```

reference: [recursive reduce arrays using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33558674/recursive-reduce-arrays-using-jq/33559836#33559836)

Comment: I created a hoo.jq file and run command. But, I have an compile error `error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER`. How can I solve it? Thanks a lot